# mysql query to retrieve first 2 records for each item type

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like

```
rowid    item      item title
1        pen       pen 1
2        pen       pen 2
3        pencil    pencil 1
4        pencil    pencil 2
5        pen       pen 3
6        paper     paper 1
7        pencil    pencil 3
8        paper     paper 2
9        paper     paper 3
```

I need a query that can output like this in mysql

```
rowid    item      item title
1        pen       pen 1
2        pen       pen 2
6        paper     paper 1
8        paper     paper 2
3        pencil    pencil 1
4        pencil    pencil 2
```

I mean for each distinct item the query need to output first 2 item titles
also please give me the query

to get last 10 or n rows for each item instead of first 2 rows

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 10.1.16-MariaDB

Comment: See last tag...

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
select @rn := 1, @itemLag := '';

select rowid, item, itemTitle from (
    select rowid, 
           case when @itemLag = item then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 end rn, 
           @itemLag := item, 
           item, 
           itemTitle
    from tbl
    order by item, rowid
) a where rn <= 2
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obzH4Mug8eVipNe6fVwXW2/0)

Comment: I didn't know about DB Fiddle +1.  Both Rextester and SQLFiddle are simultaneously down right now, so I borrowed your demo setup.

Comment: I used to post setups in answers, but now I post demos instead. I'm really happy that it could serve for someone :)

Comment: @Praveen Did any of the answers solved your problem? If so, you should mark correct answer as acceepted (green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem which is best suited for analytic functions like row number and rank.  But, since your version of MariaDB does not support them, we have to find a workaround.

One approach, which does not require any dynamic SQL, is to create a query which finds the minimum and second-to-minimum `rowid` values for each group of items.  Then, we simply join the original table to this subquery to retain only the first two matching rows.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.item, b.min_rowid, MIN(a.rowid) AS next_min_rowid
    FROM yourTable a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT item, MIN(rowid) AS min_rowid
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY item
    ) b
        ON a.item = b.item
    WHERE a.rowid > b.min_rowid
    GROUP BY a.item, b.min_rowid
) t2
    ON t1.item = t2.item AND (t1.rowid = t2.min_rowid OR t1.rowid = t2.next_min_rowid)
ORDER BY
    t1.item, t1.rowid;
```

### Demo

Comment: can you let me know, if i need last 10 or n rows for each item instead of first 2 rows

Comment: You can't easily do that without either analytic functions (which you don't have) or session variables.  If you need top n per group, then go with the answer by @Michal given above.

Comment: But I would ask that you _not_ change your question now.  You asked for top 2, and these are the answers you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would use correlated subquery with `LIMIT` clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT t1.rowid 
                FROM table t1
                WHERE t1.item = t.item
                ORDER BY t1.itemtitle
                LIMIT 2 
               );
```

If you want latest `itemtitle` then do `ORDER BY t1.itemtitle DESC` & modify `LIMIT` clause with `10` or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, assuming that there are at least two rows for each item:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rowid <= (select t2.rowid
                  from t2
                  where t2.item = t.item
                  order by t2.rowid
                  limit 1, 1
                 );
```

You can handle items with only one row by using `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rowid <= coalesce( (select t2.rowid
                            from t2
                            where t2.item = t.item
                            order by t2.rowid
                            limit 1, 1
                           ),
                           t.rowid
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  *,
  row_number() over (partition by item order by rowid asc) as rank 
  from yourtable
  qualify rank <= 2
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?